# Place the Dist directory on UWAMP and apache servers

Tags: npm, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I have created this app with Vue Cli 4.0, modified nothing:

```
vue create hello-world
```

Then I do this command :

```
NPM RUN BUILD
```

There is now a DIST directory with the app content, ready to be pushed on a web server.

I place the DIST directory app on 2 differents Apache servers :

I see a Blank screen, and / are added the beginning of the index.html links, so no links are working at all.

Do you know how to do a simple Build ? It is currently unusable it doesn't work at all .

There is the screen after that I have removed each of the / in index.html, The screen is not black any more please notice that pictures are missing too , i don't even know where is the link .
[image]

When I'm trying to use the ABOUT route, it doesn't work at all too, please look at the console error, he can't find the correct links no mo  :

```
GET http://localhost/js/about.0a9fbcd5.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]

ChunkLoadError: "Loading chunk about failed.
(error: http://localhost/js/about.0a9fbcd5.js)"
    Webpack 20
vue-router.esm.js:2079:16
    c vue-router.esm.js:2079
    h vue-router.esm.js:2124
    l vue-router.esm.js:1897
    Vt vue-router.esm.js:1962
    rt es.promise.js:110
    r microtask.js:26
```

**NOTE :**

If I install serve https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve and i type this directly inside of the dist folder :

```
serve
```

Now i can access the dist app from http://localhost:5000 inside of my navigator, and everything runs flawless.

**The problem is this :**

As long as I place the dist folder inside of my apache server UWAMP 3.10, it wont work, as well as online on another modern apache server .

Do you know if Vue can't be used from an apache server any more as long as it is generated by webpack ?

**EDIT :** HEY ! Placed the whole DIST content inside of a NODE.JS server, inside a PUBLIC directory served by the node backend , like this :

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

And now the app is currently  working ! I guess It's time to abandon Apache servers when using webpack  ?.

Comment: If it does not work, the odds are high you have not properly configured your apache server to work with History API applications.

Comment: I just created a brand new vue application using the CLI, built the directory, and using docker and the `httpd:alpine` image made a very quick check. it works just fine, but the server is not setup out-of-the box for history API fallback routes. we will likely need more information about your apache config to move forward